# How to find intersect of two parametric equations in 3D space?

Tags: geometry, matlab, parametric

Here is a question I need to practise but I am struggling with the line S and how to find the intersect. Can you help?

Consider the following line equations in the 3D space:

$$r:\begin{cases}
x=3-\lambda \\
y=1+2\lambda \\
z=-4+3\lambda \\
\end{cases}
s:\begin{cases}
x+2y+3z=a \\
3x-2y+z=-a \\
\end{cases}$$

a) Find the value of 'a' knowing that both lines intersect at one point. Find the coordinated of the intersection point.

b) For the previous value of 'a', find the plane equation \pi that contains both lines.

c) Represent the plane, the intersection point and both lines using Matlab.

Comment: Plugg the left x y z in right expressions.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

- plug $x,y,z$ from $r$ in $s$ and find $\lambda$ and $a$
- find normal vector $\vec n$ of $\pi$ by cross product of $\vec v\in r$ and $\vec w \in s$

notably we obtain

- $12\lambda-7=a$
- $-4\lambda+3=-a$

thus

- $\lambda = \frac12$
- $a=-1$

Comment: Could you please expand on this?

I have plugged in $x,y,x$ from $r$ and found:

$6\lambda-4=a$ 

$4\lambda-3=-a$ 

Do I solve as simulatenous equations for a and -a?

Comment: You need to find $\lambda$ and $a$, I check the result.

Comment: @OwenMorris check again your calculation you should obtain the equation and result I've just added if I'm not wrong.

Comment: You're not wrong. My bad, I've seen my mistake in summing up. I now have $\lambda=1/2$ and $a=-1$.

How do I go about finding the vectors? 

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @OwenMorris As explained in the hint, one way is ti find two vectors and calculate the cross product,  in this way you find a vector normal to both line and thus orthogonal to the plane containing the two lines. Are you aware about cross product and about plane equation?

Comment: I don't know how to apply the cross product and plane equation.

Comment: @OwenMorris for cross product take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590734/finding-the-3rd-axis-in-3d-space/2590738#2590738

Comment: @OwenMorris and for plane equation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658300/computing-the-normal-of-a-plane-given-3-points/2658302#2658302

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I know from the previous work we did that the intercept coordinates are 2.5,2,-2.5.

I've read through cross product and plane equation, I don't understand how to apply this

Comment: @OwenMorris Now that you know the equation os the two lines ypu can need to find  $\vec v\in r$ and $\vec w \in s$. HINT is $P_1$ and $P_2$ are 2 points $\in r$ then $\vec v = P_2-P_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\lambda$ and $a$ to be also variables, together with $x,y,z$.
You have a linear, non homogeneous, system of five equations in five variables, to be solved by any method you prefer.